# Scanner.nextLine input skipping

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to take two strings as input from user. I'm using `Scanner.nextLine()`

```
try {
    firstChoice = in.nextInt();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid option");
}

if(firstChoice == 1) {
    if(accNumber < numOfAccounts)
    {
        System.out.print("Account Title: ");
        String t = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Account Holder's name: ");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        .....
```

But on the output window, it shows:

```
Account Title: Account Holder's name:
```

It's not waiting for the first input. Why's that? It works correctly with `Scanner.next()` but I want to read the complete lines as the name can consist of more than one part.

Comment: Are there any other code before those that are reading user inputs? Please show more code.

Comment: Do you have any `nextInt`/`nextDouble`... before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) reads *only* the `int` value and skips the `\n` (when you press *enter* key right after). You should add another [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) right after the `nextInt` to consume the `\n`.

Update your code to:

```
try {
   firstChoice = in.nextInt();
   nextLine();
}
```

And you'll be fine.